# Multiplying a user's input depending on what he chooses

Tags: ruby, hash

I tried looking for some similar cases here but was unsuccessful.

I want the user to first introduce an amount of money, then he would need to state a number of days: "30", "45" or "60", not other options rather than these, and finally, the program would multiply the amount of money per a fixed number. This number depends on the number of days the user has chosen. If he choses 30, "amount of money * 1.0219"; 45: "amount of money * 1.0336"; 60: "amount of money * 1.0467".

So far, this is the  code I wrote:

```
puts "Indicate money to invest"
money_invested = gets.to_i 

puts "Indicate time of investment"
time_investment = gets.to_i

investment_calculation = { 30 => 1.0219, 45 => 1.0336, 60 => 1.0467 }
# will be `nil` if not one of the defined ones
```

I understand that there is something horrible going on within the hash already, so I decided to stop there. I'm not sure if `=>` means what I want it to mean, i.e.: multiply.

Comment: You could use a hash (`mult  = investment_calculation[time]`) to get the multiplier, but you could also use an `if` statement (`mult = if time==30 then 1.0219; elsif time==45 then 1.0336; else 1.0467; end`) or a `case` statement (`mult = case time; when 30 then  1.0219; when 45 then 1.0336; else 1.0467; end`.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the 'fixed values' in a hash and access them depending on the given user-input. E.g.:

```
fixed_values = { "30" => 1.0219,
                 "45" => 1.0336, 
                 "60" => 1.0467 }
```

Then you have to multiply it with the `*` operator:

```
investment_calculation = money_invested * fixed_values[time_investment]
```

Of course, you should check if the 'number of days', the user types in, is available in your hash, in order to avoid errors or misbehaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your response, very much useful. So, I wasn't that wrong with the hash then. My question: how can I now inform the user about the resulting operation? I was thinking about using `print`or `puts`, but how can I call the hash to put that result? Thanks.

Comment: The result has nothing to do with the hash then. It is stored in `investment_calculation`, so you have to call `puts investment_calculation.to_s`.

Comment: I got the _*: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum_ typical error at line `investment_calculation = money_invested * fixed_values[time_investment]`. Any ideas?

Comment: Multiplying a `Fixnum` (eg. `money_invested`) by `nil` raises an exception. When the `fixed_values` hash lacks a particular key it returns `nil`, so the `time_investment` key you are using is not present in the hash. Remember that `30` and `"30"` are not the same thing; one is a `Fixnum` and the other is a `String`. Make sure the key is the correct type.

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed the error and was then able to generate the output as I wanted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you question is very basic, is well written and easy to understand. Good job!

Now follow me: a Hash, also known as a "Map" in some other non-Ruby languages, is a data-structure that allows us to associate keys with values. Keys in hashes are the equivalent of indexes in arrays: the main purpose of arrays is to store and access elements by using indexes, the main purpose of hashes is to store and access elements by keys. Hashes are **really** fast when compared against other naive implementations of a generic key-value data structure.

In this example, you are associating the key `30` to the value `1.0219`. You can evaluate the behaviour of your hash in the console using the `irb` command:

```
> investment_calculation = { 30 => 1.0219, 45 => 1.0336, 60 => 1.0467 }
=> {30=>1.0219, 45=>1.0336, 60=>1.0467}
> investment_calculation[30]
=> 1.0219
> investment_calculation[45]
=> 1.0336
> investment_calculation[100]
=> nil
```

In comparison, you could solve the problem using an array with sparse values, i.e., with many values set to `0`/`nil`, but its memory-inefficient as most of the memory is used to store nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and kind words Damiano. It really encourages me to keep learning. I really understood now the difference between arrays and hashes. Now the question is: how can I display the result of the operation? I mean, let's suppose the user chose `money_invested = 1000` and `time_invested = 30`. The resulting number should be **1021.9**. How can I make the user reach that number?